# save changes of DataGridView to database

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a form with a `DataGridView` and a delete `Button`
and I have this code for delete a row, how can make this delete saved to the database? I filled the `dataGridView1` with `DataSet`.

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].IsNewRow != true)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.CurrentRow);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose in your `Table` you have a column named `id` and you want to delete from database based on `id`. Try this:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
       var id = item.Cells[0].Value.ToString();//You can change id and Cells[0] as your need
       //Write Delete code like this (Delete from Table where id = @id)
       dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);//Remove from dataGridView1
    }
}
```