# DataGridView SelectedRows returns null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I don't get why the `SelectedRows.ToString()` returns something null even when I look at the [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of Microsoft.

So here's my code :

```
DataGridViewRow row = dgvTransaction.SelectedRows[0];
string tempcid = row.Cells[0].ToString();
dbop.delete_command(String.Format("DELETE FROM CERAMIC WHERE CERAMIC_ID = '{0}'",tempcid));
```

Is there anything wrong here? the `DataGridView` source is a `DataSet` from database though and I have changed the selection mode to full row selection also.

I've been searching for the question on stack overflow about selected rows and none of them answered my question. maybe a little bit of answer would help me ^^

EDIT 1

[save changes of DataGridView to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451191/save-changes-of-datagridview-to-database)

That helps me, thanks mate

Comment: Have a look at this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451191/save-changes-of-datagridview-to-database

Comment: What event handler does that code sit in?

Comment: @Balah : it's on delete event handler, delete is Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited my code to

```
DataGridViewRow row = dgvTransaction.SelectedRows[0];
string tempcid = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
dbop.delete_command(String.Format("DELETE FROM CERAMIC WHERE CERAMIC_ID = '{0}'",tempcid));

dgvTransaction.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
dgvTransaction.Refresh();
```

and it works. thanks